# FTYPE/ASSOC priority and adding to OpenWithList from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

(Not sure if this belongs on superusers, but it seems there is a cmd.exe tag here, so here goes...)

As background, I'm working on a Firefox add-on (This question does not require knowledge of Firefox, btw, as Firefox add-ons can call the command line.) The add-on aims to build different kinds of shortcuts to cmd.exe (especially for the sake of my project https://github.com/brettz9/webappfind which allows files to be opened directly from the desktop into web apps).

Anyways, I'd like to give users the option to associate these shortcuts:

1. As the default handler for specific file extensions or file types.
2. To show up within the Open With list of applications (even if the user opts not to make the apps as default handlers)

As far as the default handling, I have found the `ftype` and `assoc` (and `associate`) commands, but I have read that user selections will override their behavior. Is there some way to ensure that I can get priority from the command line in associating file extensions to types and specific executables (until the user changes it again), or if it is not possible, then at least through C++ or the like?

As far as the Open With list:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\<file extension>\OpenWithList
```

...in my testing (with an exe), this command:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.svg\OpenWithList /v d /d D:\wamp\www\webappfind\cplusplus\WebAppFinder-view-mode-Firefox.exe
```

...did cause the exe file to show up in:

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.svg\OpenWithList
```

...but it did not show up when I subsequently right-clicked a file with the ".svg" extension.

I would really appreciate any help with these two points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\MYFOO.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\MYFOO.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.myfoo]
"Application"="MYFOO.EXE"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.myfoo\OpenWithList]
"a"="MYFOO.EXE"
"MRUList"="a"
```

So I got to an investigation what makes those file associations. It appears that you have to create a mapping from the bare EXE name to the full path as shown in the first two long-ish lines. Then you must only use the EXE name in the .extension branch. Setting the .extension's Application value will give you your default app instantly. Remember, only use `APP.EXE`, its full path must be defined as above. This was your main error. The "%1" part allows you to customize the parameters of your program so that it doesn't have to be just the opened document in quotes, as shown here. The backslashes are just escape characters for Regedit, you may discard them as you see fit.

The OpenWithList is tricky in the sense that there are letters for entries and just a blind write may overwrite some of the user's favorite apps. One approach would be to call your item "z" to lower the probability of overwriting. The right way would be enumerating the key and giving your app the first free letter. The MRUList is not essential, although it should have each used letter once and yours bumped to the start.

Note about user friendliness: Explorer will cache these values until next reboot. Make sure you update the registry and place exe first and create your file later. Although the caching only fully influences the display of the file and when it is run, the registry is read again and it will execute as you want.

TIP: If you decide to use Regedit instead of `reg`, the `/s` parameter skips the confirmation message and applies the values right away. Make sure you use double backslashes in the full path as shown. When preparing your temporary .reg file, make sure you append two CRLF's to the end or a glitch may cause your last line of code to be ignored. This sample starts with REGEDIT4 which signifies an ANSI file. If you need support for Unicode in your app path, you'll have to start the file with `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` and store it in UTF16. This is already a superior solution to calling `reg` because there's no way you could get CMD.EXE to process special UTF stuff through the command line without mangling.

Comment: Very eager to try this out and aim to do so within the next day or at least before the bounty ends. Thank you!

Comment: I am too busy at the moment to get to a full confirmation, but your work inspired me to find other helpful links as well (see https://github.com/brettz9/executable-builder/commit/ace744555385b61771fdf98d8d54f8b66611830b#diff-f120a35df9cdfce8a669cfadfaa86f3b ) particularly that OpenWithProgids is preferred over OpenWithList from XP on, and SHChangeNotify with the SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED event can cause the association (one ex. used VBScript) to avoid a system restart. Thank you, very, very much!