# How can I use the Open With function in File explorer to open a text file in my application?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a text editor in Visual Basic. It mostly works but I want to be able to click on a *.txt file in explorer and choose Open With to open it in my program. How can I implement this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21082752/62576 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/20205965

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need all of File Explorer to accomplish this. Use the `OpenFileDialog` class. The you can read the file into the text box. Make sure the text box you are using has Multiline set to True.

```
Private Sub OpenFileInTextBox()
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
    OFD.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    OFD.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    Dim fileSelected As String = ""
    If OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        fileSelected = OFD.FileName
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not file selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileSelected)
End Sub
```